# Finding triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, triangularization

If I have the matrix:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 & 1 \\ -10 & 5 & 3 \\ -2 & 1 & 3  \end{pmatrix} $$

I know the matrix $M$ is triangularisable, but I am not sure how to find $A$ such that $M=P^{-1}AP$ to find the corresponding triangular matrix $A$.

So far I have found the eigenvalues are $2,3$, then once I do $M-3I$,  I get that the basis for that matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T$. However I am not sure how to go any further? Can someone show me how? Thanks!

Comment: $P$ is the matrix with linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ and $M$ is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri The matrix $M$ is *not* diagonalizable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos True. My bad. I thought the OP had found two eigenvectors for $\lambda=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector $(1,2,2)$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$ and the vector $(0,-1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$. Now, consider the equation$$M.(x,y,z)=2(x,y,z)+(0,-1,1).$$One solution of this system is $(1,3,0)$. So, if $v_1=(1,2,2)$, $v_2=(0,-1,1)$, and $v_3=(1,3,0)$, you have $M.v_1=3v_1$, $M.v_2=2v_2$, and $M.v_3=2v_3+v_2$. So, take$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\2&-1&3\\2&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $P$ are the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$). Then$$P^{-1}MP=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Say for example could you have chosen $M.(x,y,z)=3(x,y,z)+(1,2,2)$ too?

Comment: No; that system has no solution. I chose $2$ because $2$ is a multiple root of the characteristic polynomial of $M$. On the other hand, $3$ is a simple root.

Comment: I see, so you can only choose the multiple root, what happens if you have three distinct roots?

Comment: Then every root is a single root and the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, however $P^{-1}AP$ does not equal $M$

Comment: Let$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$Since $P^{-1}MP=A$, then $PAP^{-1}=M$. So, the matrix that you're after is actually$$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & 1 & 1 \\ 6 & -2 & -1 \\ 4 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$